# jQuery Validation Depends and Require from Group

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, depends

I have rules that validate a group (requires one of 3). That works fine, however, I need to only have the 1 of 3 requirement depend on a selection in the form.

```
rules: {
  cloudfront_7: {
    require_from_group: {
      depends: function(element) {
        if ($( "#classify" ).val() == "PIC" ){
          return false;
        } else {
          return [1, ".verification-group"];
        }
      }
    }
  },
  cloudfront_8: {
    require_from_group: {
      depends: function(element) {
        if ($( "#classify" ).val() == "PIC" ){
          return false;
        } else {
          return [1, ".verification-group"];
        }
      }
    }
  },
  cloudfront_9: {
    require_from_group: {
      depends: function(element) {
        if ($( "#classify" ).val() == "PIC" ){
          return false;
        } else {
          return [1, ".verification-group"];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I noticed that it just returns `true` instead of the code I wrote, which is necessary for the `require_from_group()` function.

Comment: it should require when PIC is selected or otherwise? cause looks like `if else` return statements are inversed

Comment: if PIC is selected it should not require

Comment: Try actually removing the nested `depends` from `require_from_group`, it should work as `require_from_group:[1, ".verification-group"], depends: function(element){[..]}`

Comment: That doesn't work, that will require from group at all times and the conditional doesn't take effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem using these custom rules:

```
var verDoc_required = {
  cloudfront_7: {
    require_from_group: [1, ".verification-group"]
  },
  cloudfront_8: {
    require_from_group: [1, ".verification-group"]
  },
  cloudfront_9: {
    require_from_group: [1, ".verification-group"]
  }
}

$("#classify").change(function() {
  if ( $(this).val() == "PIC" ) {
    removeRules(verDoc_required);
  } else {
    addRules(verDoc_required);
  }
});

function addRules(rulesObj) {
  for (var item in rulesObj) {
     $('#' + item).rules('add', rulesObj[item]);
  }
}
function removeRules(rulesObj) {
  for (var item in rulesObj) {
     $('#' + item ).rules('remove');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try this code:

```
rules: {
cloudfront_7: {
require_from_group: {
param: [1, "..verification-group"],
depends: function(element) {return .....}
       }
    },
cloudfront_8: {
require_from_group: {
param: [1, "..verification-group"],
depends: function(element) {return .....}
       }
    },
cloudfront_9: {
require_from_group: {
param: [1, "..verification-group"],
depends: function(element) {return .....}
       }
    },
}
```